# only able to upload some photo files to server

Tags: php, android, server, photo

In the application the idea is to for users to be able to send photo's to one another. Using picker intent to select the photo, it previews just fine and user confirms send.  The uri is sent to background service which uploads the photo to the server after getting real path using a URL connection.  The entire process works great...but only for certain folders or image types it seems. This is my problem. What variable am I missing here?? Is it permissions i'm missing, file-type incompatibility, file-naming issues??

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

     public void transfer(String id, String handle) {
            photoToHandle = handle;
            photoToId = id;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1999);
        }

//onActivity Result passes data to dialog fragment here
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1999 && resultCode == -1) {
                if (data == null) return;
                Bundle pBundle = new Bundle();
                pBundle.putString("handle", photoToHandle);
                pBundle.putString("id", photoToId);
                pBundle.putString("uri", String.valueOf(data.getData()));
                send_photo_dialog sfd = new send_photo_dialog();
                sfd.setArguments(pBundle);
                sfd.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.mydialog);
                sfd.setCancelable(false);
                sfd.show(getFragmentManager(), "sfd");
            }
        }

//dialog confirms visually to user the image is correct and they want to send it here
        public class send_photo_dialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Context context;
        private ImageView image;
        private String fileString;
        private String[] data;
        private Activity activity;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_photo_dilaog_layout, container, false);
            fileString = getArguments().getString("uri");
            data = new String[3];
            data[0] = getArguments().getString("id");
            data[1] = fileString;
            SharedPreferences user = context.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            data[2] = user.getString("handle"," ");
            TextView handle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.town);
            handle.setText(getArguments().getString("handle"));
            TextView ok = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.send);
            TextView cancel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            ok.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileString));
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                if (stream != null) stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (bitmap != null) {
                Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int screenWidth = size.x;
                int screenHeight = size.y;

                int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

                while (bitmapHeight > (screenHeight - 200) || bitmapWidth > (screenWidth - 100)) {
                    bitmapHeight = (int) (bitmapHeight * .7);
                    bitmapWidth = (int) (bitmapWidth * .7);
                }
                BitmapDrawable resizedBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, false));
                image.setImageDrawable(resizedBitmap);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("nineteenVibrate"));
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("nineteenClickSound"));
            if (v.getId() == R.id.send) {
                Intent send = new Intent("nineteenSendPhoto");
                send.putExtra("data", data);
                context.sendBroadcast(send);
            }
            dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            context = activity.getApplicationContext();
            this.activity = activity;
        }

    }
//Service Broadcast Receiver picks up the intent here and passes it to uploadPhoto method.

    case "nineteenSendPhoto":
         uploadPhoto(intent.getStringArrayExtra("data"));
    break;



private void uploadPhoto(final String[] data) {
    if (!networkIsActive()) {
        Toaster.toastlow(this, "Try Again Later");
        return;
    }
    final String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(data[1]));
    if (imagePath == null) {
        LOG.l("imagePath is null");
        return;
    }
    final File sourceFile = new File(imagePath);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) return;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int code = 0;
            String upLoadServerUri = SITE_URL + "posting_photoz.php";
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            DataOutputStream dos;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(8000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", imagePath);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + imagePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        fileInputStream.close();
                        code = 0;
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userId\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(String.valueOf(data[0]));
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"handle\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(String.valueOf(data[2]));
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                code = conn.getResponseCode();
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.l(String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return code;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer code) {
            super.onPostExecute(code);
            if (code == 200) Toast("Photo Sent!");
            else Toast("Try Again Later");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
//Here is the php on the server side that puts the file in the correct folder and (hidden but working properly) notifies the intended receiver via gcm to download said photo. 


     <?php
$userId=$_POST['userId'];
$handle=$_POST['handle'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
try {
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }


    switch ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], "photos/".$name)){
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the response code is always 200 (success) but only some of the files show up in the /photos folder

Comment: Your php file is not echo()ing anything back to the client. Add error checking and echoing() to that script. In your android client add code to read that page. Now you are blind as you dont know what happens.

Comment: Use `isset()` in your script to begin with. And move_uploaded_file() has a return value which tells you if the file could be moved. Use that value to report/echo to the client.

Comment: You have nothing in the last catch statement. No logging. No print stack trace. Ignore? No. Handle. Again you are blind as you will never know that catch. Add all those things. And fill in a code = -1 so that in onPostExecute you know what happened.

Comment: `if (sourceFile.isFile(`. Check if the file exists before you start an AsyncTask. Like you do for network connection. And report to the user with a Toast.

Comment: `if (!networkIsActive()) {
                Toaster.toastlow(this, "Try Again Later");`. That is a non informative toast. Why dont you tell that the network is not available? Inform!

Comment: Thank your all for your input. I also have a constant display of the network state already implemented elsewhere so the user is well informed of the network state. So besides the user not yet knowing whats going on. Why am I able to upload photos from downloads/messenger folders but not the others?  This is my question.

Comment: You can find out that if you make a decent php script as i suggested. And add the checks in android i suggested. Why do you think i made them? Why this neglecting? So show your new php scrript and then we continue.

Comment: Okay ive used the php manuals example and now even the files I was successful in uploading before dont upload now.  If I could pick up the echo after the upload in the urlConnection would be nice.

Comment: The problem seems to be when the image file is large. Such as photos taken by the users camera. What can I do about this? Is it possible to decrease the photo quality or scale it down and save it to a file first?

Comment: The upload file limit is caused by the webserver or by php. Go to their settings. You can easily read the echos by opening the input stream of the connection. Such code is posted here every day. Google for convert input stream to string. Of course you can resize first.

Comment: Use isset() for every $_POST parameter.